# Как подключится к mongodb из клиентского javascript?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, браузер

доброго дня, уважаемые JavaScript-гуру. Есть ли возможность напрямую подключится к mongodb из клиентского javascript? у меня есть большая mongodb-база и хотел напрямую читать из нее данные для отображения в веб-приложении без лишних посредников на бекенде. среди монгодб-драйверов нашел лишь написанные для node.js, но не для клиенсткого JavaScript. существуют ли варианты подключиться напрямую из браузера? на форумах находил близкие вопросы, но там было только болтовня на тему, что такие варианты не нужны вообще и никаких примеров подключения

Answer (score 1):

Процесс mongod имеет простой REST api, который отключен по умолчанию. У него нет поддержки insert, update и delete операций и он предназначен для административных задач. Чтобы его включить нужно запустить монгу с ключом --rest. См. https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/tools/http-interfaces/#simple-rest-api